# Nagios for Windows - Where to find it

Tags: windows, nagios

I would like to install Nagios on my Windows 7.

I know there used to be a version for windows, but I can't find it anywhere.

Do you have any idea where to look? Or maybe some other way to easily host Nagios on my Windows 7? (Without a virtual machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've know about two options, but I haven't tried them:

1. [Nagios installer for Windows](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Distributions/Nagios-Core-32bit-Windows-Installer/details) (only 32 bit installer)
2. [Nagwin](https://www.itefix.no/i2/nagwin)

You might want to take a look [here](http://exchange.nagios.org/), this site is dedicated for all kinds of extensions for Nagios.

Have fun.

Comment: Nagios installer won't work on 64 bit OS.